# Creating wpf Installer dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, winforms, installation

Mine is an MVC web application which keeps different utilities on file server, we provide links to download them. As I was suggested, I want to create some installer so that end user will see our UI while downloading the app.
I want my installer to do
- Download the application exe file from the file server (I will provide a link for that)
- Run the app exe so that user can install the application.

I have many application files (5000+) I want to create a single installer which will call its related application itself (some data will be passed)

NOTE : WPF is not necessary I can create a normal window application too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what exactly is your question and what've you tried?

Comment: Use NSIS for this...

Comment: @Kooki I want  to create a single installer for all my applications. It should be dynamic so that it works for whichever application it is called for.

Comment: [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.120).ASPX)? Wise? I'm afraid the old .msi installer is dead. Mage.exe is a commandline tool that can be used for deploying applications, it's possible to create a script that does the work for you. But it will require a bit of work, and it will vary a bit on what you are deploying.